# How to create object without view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create player object, without views for this object model, and without additional parameters. This is action create for this object:`

```
def create
  @player = @tournament.players.new

  if @player.save
    redirect_to @tournament
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

This object also don't need additional parameters, because all parameters where set by default. As you can see, I tried resolve my problem with 
"render :nothing => true" but this don't work, and this is resoult:

> Missing template players/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}.

Update:

Routes.rb

```
resources :users
  resources :tournaments do
    resources :players
    resources :rounds do
      resources :duels
    end
  end
end
```

Server logs:

> Started GET "/tournaments/1/players/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-11 17:37:00 +0100
>     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
>   Processing by PlayersController#new as HTML
>     Parameters: {"tournament_id"=>"1"}
>     Tournament Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tournaments".* FROM "tournaments" WHERE "tournaments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template players/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :xml], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
>     * "/home/adam/workspace/tc/app/views"
>     * "/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
>   ):
>
> Started GET "/tournaments/1/players/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-11 17:37:01 +0100
>   Processing by PlayersController#new as HTML
>     Parameters: {"tournament_id"=>"1"}
>     Tournament Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tournaments".* FROM "tournaments" WHERE "tournaments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template players/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
>     * "/home/adam/workspace/tc/app/views"
>     * "/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
>   ):

Player create button, rendered in action tournaments#index: (probably problem starts here)

```
%td= link_to 'Join', new_tournament_player_path(tournament), class: "btn btn-primary btn-md"
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It's looking for the new view file in the create action?

Comment: Yeah something is off here - Rails would by convention look for `/players/create.html.erb` unless your controller redirects or renders explicitly (like  `render :nothing => true`). Check the server logs if your create action is even being called. It might help if you include the exact steps you performed and your routes.rb

Comment: @japed I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the server log your create action is not even being called here:

```
Started GET "/tournaments/1/players/new" for 127.0.0.1
...
Processing by PlayersController#new as HTML
```

[image: CRUD in Rails]

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

In Rails and REST in general the `POST` request method is used to create resources.  A `GET` request should always be idempotent and not create, alter or destroy resources on the server.

Why? Becuase `GET` requests are stored in the browser history. Hitting the back button will cause a record to be inadvertently created altered or destroyed! Not good.

If you want to create a resource in rails without having a separate `new` action or view you would use a form:

```
<%= form_for [tournament, Player.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Submitting the form will issue a request to:

```
POST /tournaments/:tournament_id/players
```

Rails offers a convenience method called [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which will create a form for you so that you have a link or button that sends the extended list of HTTP verbs (POST, PUT/PATCH, DELETE).

```
<%= button_to "Join", tournament_players_path(tournament), method: :post %>
```